# Could not find package zendframework/zend-mvc-form

Tags: php, zend-framework3

1)Try install ZF3 form components

```
 php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-mvc-form
    1/1:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$f77721936f1c90d0ef812a52e8ce1ff658380f07a75912c022c413f5376614d6.json
    Finished: success: 1, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 1


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package zendframework/zend-mvc-form in any version matching your PHP version (5.5.38.0)
```

Version PHP:
[image]

2)
I'm trying to set the developer mode:

```
 composer development-enable

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "development-enable" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shows PHP 5.6, but the error message says you are using PHP 5.5.38. zend-mvc-form requires PHP 5.6 or above.